# Joined Google Contacts do not sync

Tags: contacts, sync

I can join two contacts on my Android phone, regardless of where the contact is from (Google Contacts, Qik Video, Skype, etc). But when I join two Google contacts, I expect to see the contacts merged in Google Contacts as well, after synchronization, and this does not happen.

My phone is a Samsung Infuse. Model number: SAMSUNG-SGH-I997. Firmware version: 2.2.1

Comment: I realize I didn't explicitly ask a question. I realize that the Android "Contacts" application deals not only with Google contacts, but also "Phone" contacts and Skype, etc. But what I am looking for is a solution. For example, on my phone, I'd like to add a new contact of type "Google contacts", but I appear only to be able to make a new contact of type "Phone". I would like a solution such that my  contact information is centralized.

Comment: you haven't answered George's question about your phone's make and model and the Android version running on your phone. Contact joining on the phone has changed a lot since Android was first released so it really does make a difference which version you have. Also, as many manufacturers modify the Contacts app themselves and change things like Contacts linking and defaults it may make a difference who made your phone.

Comment: @GAThrawn: I've just updated my original question to include the phone model. Thanks.

Comment: Would exporting your contacts to Google solve the problem?  Or is it that you want to have your Skype contacts and such automatically be sent to the Google server?

Comment: I don't really care about the other contacts. I'd like a way to sync the ones I've added into my contacts manager on my phone to Google Contacts.

Answer (score 5):

Google only keeps track of your Google contacts.  The Contacts app on Android allows other apps to provide data to it.  That's how you get your Skype etc. contacts on your phone but Google can't know what they will be and can't sync them.

Comment: +1 "Merge"ing on the web is not the same thing as "join"ing on the phone. Merging takes two Contact records in GMail and combines them to form one record. Joining on the phone takes two accounts that could be from anywhere and just puts a link between them to say that these records from different sources are relating the same person.

Comment: @GAThrawn Thanks for the responses. Please see my comment on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to write here model of your phone and firmware version.

Some examples from practice.

LG Optimus One. I didn't realize very long time how to make Google Contacts from phone. It is simple. When you create contact there is on top of windows drop-down box, where are three items: `Phone` (or `PC Sync`), `SIM` `Google`. It is obvious where each item saves contact data. Default item is `Phone`. [Video how to create contact and select it's type.](http://www.metacafe.com/watch/6014039/adding_a_new_contact_lg_optimus_one_the_human_manual/)

HTC Inspire 4G. Default behavior is to create Google contacts. But there is also drop-down menu where I can select `SIM` or `Phone` items.

Please look through your phone menus more thoroughly.

Also you can make contacts directly in web-interface of GMail. After small time they will be available in phone. And when you edit such contacts, they are edited on Google server too. One thing you need to make such functionality available is to connect your phone and your Google account.

Comment: @Goerge, I've added the phone model to my original question. My phone is already registered with my Google account